# Is it save to delete old entries from the civirule_rule_log table

Tags: civirules

This table can become rather large (See the experience experts at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/89). Can old entries be deleted without losing vital information?

Answer (score 2):

This table is used to prevent that cron triggers fire two times on the same day. So entries older than a day can be deleted.

The table is also a help debugging. For example, in the 'Manage CiviRules' form, they are used to show the latest contact a rule is triggered for. This information possible dissapears if you delete the older entries.

[image]

(But beware, in the Open Source world it is always possible that you have installed an extension that this table for important actions).